# Sending multiple integers with intent

Tags: android, android-intent, integer

i am trying to send two values to another page, but everytime only one of them is working.Here is my code:
Sending:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fight_1.class);
        i.putExtra("deger2",ana_ekran_arti1_int);
        startActivity(i);

 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fight_1.class);
    i.putExtra("deger",  ana_ekran_can_int);
    startActivity(i);
```

Taking:

```
int i = getIntent().getIntExtra("deger",-1);
        int ii = getIntent().getIntExtra("deger2",-1);
        arti1= ii;
        fight_1_arti1.setText(arti1+"");
        fight_1_can_int=i;
        fight_1_can.setText(fight_1_can_int+"");
```

Comment: You only have one putExtra? You need to do another one for "deger2"

Comment: I do not see your code of setting deger2 value

Comment: Sorry, see edit.They are in different public voids, a button onclick calls them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only sending one value you have to use the same intent without creating a new object.

I hope this helps

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),fight_1.class);
i.putExtra("deger2", ana_ekran_arti1_int);
i.putExtra("deger",  ana_ekran_can_int);
startActivity(i);
```